# Save file in %temp% folder?

Tags: c++, windows, file, save, temp

I want to save file in temporary folder which can be easy found when type at run by putting "%temp%", but don't know **how to navigate to them** from c++.

I try using function like "GetTempPathA" or "GetTempFileNameA()" but they don't return char value. For my purpose I use "SaveToFile" method from "TResourceStream" and need UnicodeString, how to find those information?

Comment: those apis are what you need and do return strings. Read the docs for them. Call the W versions to get UnicodeString.

Answer (score 6):

No, neither `GetTempPath` nor `GetTempFileName` *return* a char value. In general, C functions do not ever return strings. Instead, you pass in a string buffer and the length of that string buffer, and the function *fills in* the string buffer with the requested string.

For example, to call `GetTempPath`, you would write the following code:

```
TCHAR szTempPathBuffer[MAX_PATH];
GetTempPath(MAX_PATH,            // length of the buffer
            szTempPathBuffer);   // the buffer to fill
```

`szTempPathBuffer` will contain the path to the temporary directory.

Do note that you should probably not be explicitly calling the ANSI functions (those with an `A` suffix). Windows has been fully Unicode for over a decade now. Either use the macros defined by the Windows headers, which automatically resolve to the correct version of the function depending on whether `_UNICODE` is defined, or explicitly call the Unicode versions (those with a `W` suffix).

Since you're calling the ANSI versions, you're getting an ANSI string (composed of `char` values), rather than a Unicode string (composed of `wchar_t` values), which is presumably what the `SaveToFile` method that you're trying to call expects.

Answer (score 0):

One can use also getenv(), but it's deprecated and consider as "non-safe":

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996) //disable getenv warning

char* p = getenv("TEMP");
std::string path(p);
```